# Is Canopy compatible with OS X Yosemite?

Tags: enthought, osx-yosemite

Is Canopy (version 1.4.1 seems to be current) compatible with Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite)?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs on [Ask Different](http://apple.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @hrbrmstr Enthought Canopy is a leading Python IDE; and as such is covered by "if your question generally covers … software tools commonly used by programmers" (http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Stack Overflow is the primary locus of public help for Enthought Canopy.

Answer (score 2):

We have not seen any problems such as plagued the transition to Mavericks, but statistics will tell for sure.